# How to deal with serialization and Handles in AutoCAD

Tags: c#, handle, autocad, objectarx

I want to serialize blockreference handle in an xml file and (its properties). So I store this value at the initialization :

```
blockReference.ObjectId.Handle.Value; // decimal value = 10658
```

But when I select the blockReference in AutoCAD the handle has changed.

```
private void database_ObjectModified(object sender, ObjectEventArgs e)
{
    long currentId = e.DBObject.ObjectId.Handle.Value;  // Now it's 10659 !!!!

    ...
}
```

Do I use handle no correctly ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the Handle in the XML file you need to get the `ObjectId` by its `.Handle` and then use `ObjectId` that is valid **only in the current session** to read/write the object. See http://through-the-interface.typepad.com/through_the_interface/2007/02/getting_access_.html

Look for the `Database.GetObjectId()` method in the SDK docs (the managed interface CHM file). This is it in a nutshell...

```C#
public ObjectId GetObjectId(
[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U1)] bool createIfNotFound, 
Handle objHandle, 
int identifier
);
```

- `[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U1)] bool createIfNotFound`  Input Boolean indicating to create a objectId stub if input handle is not found
- `Handle objHandle`  Input Handle object containing the handle being passed in
- `int identifier`  Reserved for future use

Answer (score 4):

Use **theEntityObj.Handle.Value**

If you get if from the ObjectId, it will change when you close/open a drawing.

Note a Handle can change in some cases, for instance, if you have a LINE inside a block, if you BEDIT the block, the HANDLES will change.

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! It was my first idea but how to get the EntityObj.Handle from the ObjectEventArgs (database.ObjectModified event) ?

Comment: Sorry but when you say "theEntityObj.Handle.Value" it means blockreference.Handle.Value in this case ?

Comment: yes, I meant "blockReference.Handle.Value" on your code. And inside the event handler, the event second arg should contain "arg.DBObject.Handle.Value"

Comment: I tried but the value of  e.DBObject.Handle.Value is different of the value of blockReference.Handle.Value; (10658 and 10659 in decimal values) :-/

Comment: Ok, it seems the object in the ObjectEventArgs is not the blockreference itself but the Attributes linked to the blockreference... That's why the handle is different. Now I should find the way to get the blockreference linked to the attribute

Comment: you probably need to check the type of e.DBObject to skip what you don't want... this event will trigger several times during a single user action, so filter is a 'must have'.

Comment: `DBObject.Handle` and `DBObject.Id.Handle` are the same thing. The handles do not change when the drawing is closed and reopened, Ids change.

Comment: Thank you Maxence. Now I have another bug... In my database_ObjectModified method (ObjectModified event) the using (Transaction tr = database.TransactionManager.StartTransaction()) raises an NullReferenceException whereas when I put the code in the database_ObjectOpenedForModify (ObjectOpenedForModify event) I have not this Exception...

Comment: You cannot modify inside a modify event... that will cause an infinite loop (stackoverflow)

Comment: @Florian Please create a new question for this topic

Comment: "a Handle can change in some cases". +1 - Good point. Yes, you can do it deliberately too with `.SwapIdWith()`. See the SDK docs and http://through-the-interface.typepad.com/through_the_interface/2008/07/swapping-identi.html